# How can I query a Git repository for MSR (mining software repositories) purposes?

Tags: git, version-control, data-mining

I need to query a Git repository so that I end up with a data set of the following schema that contains all contributions to the repository:

```
user.id,
user.ip,
contribution.type,
timestamp,
commit.id,
file,
branch,
lines.added,
lines.deleted
```

for example:

```
u1,127.0.0.1,add,2015-01-01 00:00,c123456,/path/to/index.html,master,100,0
u1,127.0.0.1,mod,2015-01-01 00:00,c123456,/path/to/page1.html,master,3,6
u1,127.0.0.1,del,2015-01-01 00:00,c123456,/path/to/page2.html,master,0,200
u2,127.0.0.2,mod,2015-01-02 00:00,c654321,/path/to/index.html,master,2,2
u3,127.0.0.3,add,2015-01-03 00:00,c234567,/path/to/topic.html,topic,300,1
u4,127.0.0.4,mod,2015-01-04 00:00,c765432,/path/to/topic.html,topic,21,1
```

Note, that one line should represent one contribution to a file, not a commit, i.e. one commit may span several lines.

So far, I am fiddling around with `git log -g --numstat --decorate --source --date=iso --no-merges --all --format=%aE,%h,%ad,%gd`. I suppose I will have to postprocess the output in order to merge the infos from `--name-status` (contribution_type and file) and `--numstat` (lines.added, lines.deleted) into the format shown above. Also I haven't figured out yet how I can get the IP address – do git repositories record this information when they receive a "push"?

Answer (score 1):

Use the *log* function, and transform the data as desired.

I doubt you'll find all these informstion - the user.ip field does not make sense, because commits are not necessarily on a network.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [codemetrics](https://github.com/elmotec/codemetrics), I am the author. You may need to do some post processing. For instance, you may need to run the analysis for each branch. Also, I don’t believe that git stores the IP addresses.

Also check out the sample to get an idea of [what’s possible](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/elmotec/codemetrics/blob/master/notebooks/pandas.html).